# Decrypt MVC4 Membership Provider Password

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using web security, MembershipProvider to create User login account. I want to decrypt the password of the user for porting the data. 
Is there any way that I can decrypt the password created by Membership provider.

Thanks.

Comment: It's salted before being hashed, so no. Although oclHashCat has support for the the ASP.NET Membership Provider (the hashing isn't that strong, 1000 rounds of SHA256 IIRC), but it probably won't crack all of them.

Answer (score 0):

[Membership Provider Decrypt Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Follow this link it has by default decrypt function for the encoded password by membership[ provider.

`protected virtual byte[] DecryptPassword(
    byte[] encodedPassword
)`

Comment: When I use it in MVC 4 application I get exception saying that this method is not supported.